# How do I make the ball bounce off the paddle?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a basic pong game (paddle is a rectangle on the bottom of the screen and the ball drops from the top of the screen). I want the ball to bounce back up ONLY when it hits the paddle. So far, I've written code that will make the ball bounce off the top and bottom screen, but I'm having trouble with getting the ball to bounce off the paddle.

I have to modify the parameters that are passed to my test_collide_ball method. If it’s current x values are within the range of the paddle, then it bounces back up.

I've been trying to think of a solution for this, and what I'm thinking is that if the ball hits the paddle's y coordinate (the height), then it bounces back up. But it also has to be within the range of x coordinates that make up the paddle (so the width of the paddle).

But when I do this, the ball just gets stuck in place. Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for the ball class/methods:

```
import pygame

class Ball:
   def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, dx, dy):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.radius = radius
      self.color = color
      self.dx = dx
      self.dy = dy

   def draw_ball(self, screen):
      pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color,
         pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.radius, self.radius))

   def update_ball(self):
      self.x += self.dx
      self.y += self.dy

   def test_collide_top_ball(self, top_height):
      if (self.y <= top_height):
         self.dy *= -1

   def test_collide_bottom_ball(self, paddle):
      if (self.y == paddle.y) and (self.x >= paddle.x) and (self.x <= paddle.x + paddle.width):
         self.dy *= -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to be happening is your ball enters the collision zone and reverses it's direction. The ball is still in the collision zone, however, and it reverses it's direction again.

What you should look into is a **debounce check**. Put simply, this is code that prevents something from happening twice or more times (de-bouncing it).

From your code example, the ball's momentum is reversed when it enters the paddle zone. What you might add is a boolean flag to see if you have already detected that the ball entered the zone. When it is first detected, set the flag to true. When the ball moves outside of the zone, set the flag back to false. Only reverse the ball's momentum if the flag is false.

So, (excusing my rusty Python)

```
def test_collide_bottom_ball(self, paddle):
  if (self.y == paddle.y) and (self.x >= paddle.x) and (self.x <= paddle.x + paddle.width) and (!self.hitPaddle):
     self.dy *= -1
     self.hitPaddle = true
  else
     self.hitPaddle = false
```

And in your entity:

```
self.hitPaddle = false
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is probably a stupid question, but where would I put the entity? (Sorry, I'm completely new to python!)

Answer (score 0):

Just like @MrDoomBringer is saying, you need to prevent it from getting stuck within the pad.

One easy method to solve that is to check whether self.dy is positive - the ball is moving downwards. This way you could also add the same "within" check for the Y-pos as you did with the X-pos. Otherwise, having a collision with an exact Y-coordinate is pretty hard unless you're using the right speed etc.

Another thing - if you have a ball, you most likely want to add it's size to the equation. Then you might want to use some more fancy collision-techniques, such as this: http://www.migapro.com/circle-and-rotated-rectangle-collision-detection/